# Using Visio shape.getFormulas

Tags: vb.net, binding, visio

I would like to extract some Information out of Visio shapes using vb.net. Therefore I think shape.getFormulas is the best opportunity.

By executing this line I get the error:

> Type mismatch. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80020005
>   (DISP_E_TYPEMISMATCH))

(I read in other posts that there might be a problem if `SID_SRCStream` is defined as `Integer` an not `Int16`, but this shouldn't be the problem)

The code works VB6/VBA, so there shouldn't be any problems with sytax or definition of `SID_SRCStream`.

Does anyone has an ideas what might be wrong with my code?

**Code:**

```
Dim x as object = Nothing
Dim SID_SRCStream = New Int16(58 * 3) {}

'fill SID_SRCStream with values

With vis.ActiveDocument

        For Each page In .Pages
            If Strings.Left(page.Name, 5) = "Autom" Then
                For Each shapeX In page.Shapes
                    If Strings.Left(shapeX.Name, 15) = "Messstellen mit"   Then
                        shapeX.GetFormulas(SID_SRCStream, x)
                    End If
                Next
            End If
        Next

end With
```

Comment: I solved the issue with changing the 'for each loops' to 'for loops' but I can't explain why this one is working. Can anyone explain the difference for calling the getFormulas?

Answer (score 0):

Try 
`Dim SID_SRCStream() As Int16`
instead of your current declaration (which is not VBA).